# Is the transformer SLiM compatible with ALBERT?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

My question is about the article [Sub-Linear Memory: How to Make Performers SLiM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.11346.pdf).

It is written in the article "our algorithm is compatible with distillation [(Sanh et al., 2020)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.01108.pdf?ref=hackernoon.com)".

Now I would like to know if SLiM is compatible with parameter sharing...

Is [SLiM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.11346.pdf) compatible with [ALBERT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.11942.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1gWlaWokv7Ys5JNkTgQ3Hw-wdvwv9J5zkYE1-N0lHbqiAOlvJTfhaKuDg) and with [ELBERT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.00175.pdf)?

P.S. I am asking this question because the flow of the input through the encoder is different for BERT (and for DistilBERT too, because DistilBERT uses different loss for compreessing BERT...), ALBERT and ELBERT, look the image below taken from [ELBERT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.00175.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the authors of the SLiM-Performer paper. Yes, SLiM Performer is compatible with ALBERT-style weight sharing across layers, we mention that in Section 3.1 of the arXiv manuscript. In this case, the vector of parameters $\theta$ only stores parameters for one layer, which are retrieved by $F^{(r)}$ and $G^{(r)}$ functionals (using paper's notation).

It's also easy to see that SLiM Performer is compatible with the mentioned ELBERT model. For that, simply redefine the loss $\mathcal{L}^{(n)}$ as a "cascading" loss from ELBERT.